# What is the correct way to create a stub/mock for the Scheme property present under Uri in Rhinomocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, stub

I'm writing a Unit Test case for a c# method with the help of Rhinomocks framework. Inside my actual method I access the Scheme property from the **Uri** property present under `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` namespace.

The scheme property is accessed like `_requestContext.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme` in the actual method.

When I run my unit test case, it crashes inside my actual impletementation method when it tries to access/read the scheme property.

In order to mock the URI and Scheme properties I tried like the below ways but it doesn't work as expected.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
//requestContext.Expect(r => r.RequestMessage.RequestUri).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();

requestContext.Stub(x => x.RequestMessage.RequestUri).Return(uri);

requestContext.Stub(x => x.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme).Return("http");//this is the value the scheme should return when it is accessed inside the actual method
```

What is the correct way to create a stub/mock for the Scheme property present under Uri.

Note: I'm referring to the Uri property under System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete `Uri` used in your example will include the scheme. No need to mock it further.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");

var scheme = uri.Scheme; //return "http"    

requestContext.Stub(x => x.RequestMessage.RequestUri).Return(uri);
```

So calling `RequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme` will return the scheme from the concrete `Uri`. Which in this case would be `http`, as you already know and stated in your original post.

Also based on your comment to my original suggestion, then I suggest you create an actual `HttpRequestMessage` and populate it as needed.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

requestContext.Stub(x => x.RequestMessage).Return(request);
```

Now there is no need to mock anything else related to the request as the actual implementation is used.

Comment: tried the way specified by you, but getting exception when running the test case. System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type 'System.Uri' doesn't match the return type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' for method 'IRequestContext.get_RequestMessage();'' ... this error is thrown while executing the line: requestContext.Stub(x => x.RequestMessage.RequestUri).Return(uri);

Comment: @Krishnan Then I suggest you create an actual HttpRequestMessage and populate it as needed.